# Pass array as query parameter in OpenAPI

Tags: openapi

I want to create an GET API which should look like `?status=Active,Inactive,Registered`. Basically an array of statuses that client can use to filter the list.
Below is my Open API spec definition

```
openapi: 3.0.2
...
paths:
      /something:
        get:
          parameters:
            - in: query
              name: filter
              schema:
                $ref:  #/components/schemas/FilterValues
                explode: true
components:
  schema:
    FilterValues:
      properties:
        status:
          type: array
          $ref: "#/components/schemas/Status"
    Status:
      type: string
      enum: [Active,Inactive,Registered]
      example: "Active"
```

But this is not working well. Although when I tried the below spec it works well.

```
openapi: 3.0.2
...
paths:
      /something:
        get:
          parameters:
            - in: query
              name: filter
              schema:
                $ref:  #/components/schemas/FilterValues
                explode: true
            - in: query
              name: status
              schema: 
                type: array
                items:
                  $ref: #/components/schemas/Status

components:
  schema:
    FilterValues:
      properties:
        ...
    Status:
      type: string
      enum: [Active,Inactive,Registered]
      example: "Active"
```

Any help on what am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

In OpenAPI 3, a query parameter containing a comma-separated list of values needs to be defined as an array with `style: form` and `explode: false`. Note that `style` and `explode` are parameter-level keywords, not schema-level keywords.

The parameter `name` must be the same as appears in the query string (in your example - `status`).

Here's the correct version:

```yaml
openapi: 3.0.2
...
paths:
  /something:
    get:
      parameters:
        - in: query
          name: status    # <-------
          schema: 
            type: array
            items:
              $ref: '#/components/schemas/Status'
          style: form     # Default style value, can be omitted
          explode: false  # <-------

components:
  schema:
    Status:
      type: string
      enum: [Active,Inactive,Registered]
      example: "Active"
```

Refer to the [Parameter Serialization](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/serialization/#query) guide on swagger.io for more information.